# R - Reorder a bar plot in a function using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following plot function using `ggplot2`.

```
Function_Plot <- function(Fun_Data, Fun_Color)
{
  MyPlot <- ggplot(data = na.omit(Fun_Data), aes_string(x = colnames(Fun_Data[2]), fill = colnames(Fun_Data[1]))) +
            geom_bar(stat = "count") +
            coord_flip() +
            scale_fill_manual(values = Fun_Color)
  return(MyPlot)
}
```

The result is :

[image]

I need to upgrade my function to reorder the bar according frequencies of the words (in descending order). As I see the answer for another question about reordering, I try to introduce `reorder` function in the `aes_string` but it doesn't work.

A reproducible example :

```
a <- c("G1","G1","G1","G1","G1","G1","G1","G1","G1","G1","G2","G2","G2","G2","G2","G2","G2","G2")
b <- c("happy","sad","happy","bravery","bravery","God","sad","happy","freedom","happy","freedom",
       "God","sad","happy","freedom",NA,"money","sad")

MyData <- data.frame(Cluster = a, Word = b)
MyColor <- c("red","blue")

Function_Plot(Fun_Data = MyData, Fun_Color = MyColor)
```

Comment: Try `MyData <- as.data.frame(table(MyData[,2], MyData[,1]));MyData[,1] <- reorder(MyData[,1], MyData[,3], FUN = sum);ggplot(data = na.omit(MyData), aes_string(x = colnames(MyData[1]), y = colnames(MyData[3]), fill = colnames(MyData[2]))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if reordering doesn't work *inside* `aes_string`, let's try it beforehand.

```
Function_Plot <- function(Fun_Data, Fun_Color)
{
  Fun_Data[[2]] <- reorder(Fun_Data[[2]], Fun_Data[[2]], length)
  MyPlot <- ggplot(data = na.omit(Fun_Data), aes_string(x = colnames(Fun_Data[2]), fill = colnames(Fun_Data[1]))) +
            geom_bar(stat = "count") +
            coord_flip() +
            scale_fill_manual(values = Fun_Color)
  return(MyPlot)
}

Function_Plot()
```

[image]

Couple other notes - I'd recommend you use a more consistent style, mixing whether or not use use `_` to separate words in variable names is confusing and asking for bugs.

It won't matter much unless your data is *really* big, but extracting names from a data frame is very efficient, whereas subsetting a data frame is less efficient. Your code subsets a data frame and then extracts the column names remaining, e.g., `colnames(Fun_Data[1])`. It will be cleaner to extract the names and then subset that vector: `colnames(Fun_Data)[1]`